# How to flush listview every 4week (or to an amount of configurable time)

Tags: android, listview, timer, counter

I have a listview which i want to flush every 4week. How should i accomplish this task ? Can i use timer or shall i use counter ? Has anyone tried this earlier. Thanks for your help. Below is my code for ListView

LogListView.java

```
public class LogListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    static String newString;
    private static EntryAdapterLog adapter;
    int clickCounter = 0;
    static ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    static SharedPreferences preferences = null;
    private static Context context = null;
    static StringTokenizer tokens;
    static String first;
    private static String second;
    private JSONArray jsonarry = null;
    static String saveitems;
    private JSONObject jsonobject = null;
    private String subtitle;
    static String title;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;
        adapter = new EntryAdapterLog(this, items);
        // items.add(new SectionItem("Log Report"));
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        if (adapter.getCount() != 0) {
            // Do nothing Adapter has value
        } else {
            retreiveItems();
        }

    }

    // Method which will handle dynamic insertion
    public static void addItems() {

        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOG",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        newString = preferences.getString("log", "");

        tokens = new StringTokenizer(newString, ",");
        first = tokens.nextToken();
        second = tokens.nextToken();

        items.add(new EntryItem(first, second));

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    // Method which will handle dynamic insertion ends

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        saveItems();
    }

    // Save ListItems if restarted
    protected static void saveItems() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("prefName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("myList", new Gson().toJson(items).toString());
        editor.apply();
        Log.d("LOG", "Saved Items : " + items);
    }
    // Save ListItems if restarted ends

    // Retrieve ListItems if restarted
    protected void retreiveItems() {
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("prefName",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        saveitems = preferences.getString("myList", "");
        Log.d("LOG", "Retreived Items : " + saveitems);

        try {
            jsonarry = new JSONArray(saveitems);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (jsonarry == null || jsonarry.length() == 0) {
            return;                                                                        //This checks before setting adapter onCreate if adapter is null
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarry.length(); i++) {

            try {
                jsonobject = jsonarry.getJSONObject(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // get all values here from JSONObject
            title = jsonobject.optString("title");
            subtitle = jsonobject.optString("subtitle");

            items.add(new EntryItem(title, subtitle));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }
    // Retrieve ListItems if restarted ends

    // Counter for amount of period of time before flusing adapter
    protected void flushList(){

    }
    // Counter for amount of period of time before flusing adapter ends

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        if (!items.get(position).isSection()) {
            items.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        if (position == 9) {

        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }

}
```

Regards

Comment: do you want to flush items from the preferences? you use Alarm manager to shedule a task.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider an `AlarmManager`, [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)!
Trying to run a timer or counter for 4 weeks is a waste of lots of resources.